# How can I eliminate whitespace at the bottom of my site?

Tags: css, whitespace, footer

I have some white space at the bottom of my site and I'm stuck on how to eliminate it. There's no padding or margins, just extra space that I'd like to remove. Happens when screen is 600px or less. This is the URL: http://mbenjamin.digilab.io/

I've thought of whatever I could; but I need another pair of eyes on this now...

Comment: I don't see any white space

Comment: Don't float your `.site-inner` and then fix the rest of the messy positioning.

Answer (score 2):

style.css line 1584(ish)

```
div.footer-credits {
    float: left;
    font-size: 11.9px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;*********right here****
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```